# How to work with javascript Map without mutations

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming, immutability

I'm working in a functional way in my JS project.

That's also means I do not mutate `object` or `array` entities. Instead I always create a new instance and replace an old one.

e.g.

```
let obj = {a: 'aa', b: 'bb'}
obj = {...obj, b: 'some_new_value'}
```

The question is:

**How to work in a functional (immutable) way with javascript Maps?**

I guess I can use the following code to add values:

```
let map = new Map()
...
map = new Map(map).set(something)
```

**But what about delete items?**

I cannot do `new Map(map).delete(something)`, because the result of `.delete` is a boolean.

**P.S.** I'm aware of existence of ImmutableJS, but I don't want to use it due to you never 100% sure if you are working now with a plain JS object, or with immutablejs' object (especially nested structures). And because of bad support of TypeScript, btw.

Comment: I think you can just create a new map with the deleted items filtered out? Map is just like a regular object, but instead of object create notation you create new map

Comment: @nbokmans you mean something like get `mat.entries`, filter them and create a new map, right?

Comment: A probably interesting read about the general topic may be [how-does-one-implement-hash-tables-in-a-functional-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793259/how-does-one-implement-hash-tables-in-a-functional-language).

Comment: @sergei indeed, something like `let newMap = new Map(Array.from(oldMap.entries()).filter(([key, value]) => k !== someKey))`

Comment: I'm all for functional programming but it's a topic prone to [cargo cult rituals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). It's not usually necessary to carry it to that extreme. Consider this contrived example: `function foo(n) { let arr = []; for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { arr.push(i); } return arr; }`. That's as imperative as it gets, but *only internally*: the *caller* sees the same result as the cryptic but "functional" `function foo2(n) { return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map((_, i) => i); }`

Comment: @JaredSmith I see your point. Honestly I use some eslint-extension which allow me to determine of how functional I'd like to be. I don't want much, just pure functions when possible, no mutations on function arguments and some other things.

Comment: @SergeiPanfilov that's a really good place to be IMHO.

Comment: to be fair, not using library like `immutable` because _"you never 100% sure if you are working now with a plain JS object"_ is a bad reason. well-defined barriers of abstraction (aka "modules") are the key to successful programming.

Comment: @Thankyou Oh yeah? What about nested objects then? Say you have JSON from the server with deep nesting. Would you make each of those nested objects immutable as well? Or you will wrap only root-level object? What if you have 100 developers in a project? It's a question of time when someone will make a decomposition and return un-wrapped nested object. Hard to track even through code review. Just an example. But for real I never get a good answer of what is the way to deal with nested structures in a safe way.

Comment: @Thankyou I'm even not speaking about how hard it was to have good TypeScript support alongside with ImmutableJS. Maybe things are became better in last few years. Maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot do new Map(map).delete(something);, because the result of .delete is a boolean.

You can use an interstitial variable. You can farm it out to a function if you like:

```
function map_delete(old_map, key_to_delete) {
    const new_map = new Map(old_map);
    new_map.delete(key_to_delete);
    return new_map;
}
```

Or you can create get the entries in the map, filter them and create a new one from the result:

```
const new_map = new Map( Array.from(old_map.entries).filter( ([key, value]) => key !== something ) );
```

Comment: I guess map.entries returns MapIterator, not an array, so as @nbokmans metioned, you have to use Array.from or something.

Comment: @SergeiPanfilov — You're right; that'll teach for to just skim the docs without testing it.

Comment: where you write `Array.from(old_map.entries)` i think you mean `Array.from(old_map.entries())`, but you can simplify writing `Array.from(old_map)` which does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a persistent map data structure, then you cannot get around mutations or have to conduct insanely inefficient shallow copies. Please note that mutations themselves aren't harmful, but only in conjunction with sharing the underlying mutable values.

If we are able to limit the way mutable values can be accessed, we can get safe mutable data types. They come at a cost, though. You cannot just use them as usual. As a matter of fact using them takes some time to get familiar with. It's a trade-off.

Here is an example with the native `Map`:

```js
// MUTABLE

const Mutable = clone => refType => // strict variant
  record(Mutable, app(([o, initialCall, refType]) => {
    o.mutable = {
      run: k => {
        o.mutable.run = _ => {
          throw new TypeError("illegal subsequent inspection");
        };

        o.mutable.set = _ => {
          throw new TypeError("illegal subsequent mutation");
        };

        return k(refType);
      },

      set: k => {
        if (initialCall) {
          initialCall = false;
          refType = clone(refType);
        }

        k(refType);
        return o;
      }
    }

    return o;
  }) ([{}, true, refType]));
  
const mutRun = k => o =>
  o.mutable.run(k);

const mutSet = k => o =>
  o.mutable.set(k);

// MAP

const mapClone = m => new Map(m);

const mapDelx = k => m => // safe-in-place-update variant
  mutSet(m_ =>
    m_.has(k)
      ? m_.delete(k)
      : m_) (m);
      
const mapGet = k => m =>
  m.get(k);

const mapSetx = k => v => // safe-in-place-update variant
  mutSet(m_ => m_.set(k, v));

const mapUpdx = k => f => // safe-in-place-update variant
  mutSet(m_ => m_.set(k, f(m_.get(k))));

const MutableMap = Mutable(mapClone);

// auxiliary functions

const record = (type, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type, o);

const app = f => x => f(x);

const id = x => x;

// MAIN

const m = MutableMap(new Map([[1, "foo"], [2, "bar"], [3, "baz"]]));

mapDelx(2) (m);
mapUpdx(3) (s => s.toUpperCase()) (m);

const m_ = mutRun(Array.from) (m);
console.log(m_); // [[1, "foo"], [3, "BAZ"]]

try {mapSetx(4) ("bat") (m)} // illegal subsequent mutation
catch (e) {console.log(e.message)}

try {mutRun(mapGet(1)) (m)} // illegal subsequent inspection
catch (e) {console.log(e.message)}
```

If you take a closer look at `Mutable` you see it creates a shallow copy as well, but only once, initially. You can than conduct as many mutations as you want, until you inspect the mutable value the first time.

You can find an implementation with several instances in my [scriptum library](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/f8274181647986b1338ee9552f2bf1f4f8d19eda/index.js#L4499). Here is a [post](https://dev.to/iquardt/you-might-not-need-immutability-safe-in-place-updates-g2c) with some more background information on the concept.

I borrowed the concept from Rust where it is called *ownership*. The type theoretical background are affine types, which are subsumed under linear types, in case you are interested.

Comment: @Will are you only referring to the typo or is this plain wrong? I am not sure I know what I am talking about, b/c I have no PLT background..

Comment: just the typo. _ (me neither)

Comment: I disagree with your point that it's impossible to avoid mutations. Well, actually you right, but saying practically you can specify some immutable eslint rules (that's what I do).

Comment: all I (think I) know is that a function which [has no observable effects except for producing its result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256555/849891) is allowed to use mutation on the inside. and if you limit it to just one observer per each mutations stretch you're guaranteeing it is so. (I also heard terms like "unique types" and "linear types" which seem relevant)

Answer (score 2):

**roll your own data structure**

Another option is to write your own `map` module that does **not** depend on JavaScript's native `Map`. This completely frees us from its mutable behaviours and prevents making full copies each time we wish to `set`, `update`, or `del`. This solution gives you full control and effectively demonstrates how to implement any data structure of your imagination -

```js
// main.js

import { fromEntries, set, del, toString } from "./map.js"

const a =
  [["d",3],["e",4],["g",6],["j",9],["b",1],["a",0],["i",8],["c",2],["h",7],["f",5]]

const m =
  fromEntries(a)

console.log(1, toString(m))
console.log(2, toString(del(m, "b")))
console.log(3, toString(set(m, "c", "#")))
console.log(4, toString(m))
```

We wish for the expected output -

1. map `m`, the result of `fromEntries(a)`
2. derivative of map `m` with key `"b"` deleted
3. derivative of map `m` with key `"c"` updated to `"#"`
4. map `m`, unmodified from the above operations

```
1 (a, 0)->(b, 1)->(c, 2)->(d, 3)->(e, 4)->(f, 5)->(g, 6)->(h, 7)->(i, 8)->(j, 9)
2 (a, 0)->(c, 2)->(d, 3)->(e, 4)->(f, 5)->(g, 6)->(h, 7)->(i, 8)->(j, 9)
3 (a, 0)->(b, 1)->(c, #)->(d, 3)->(e, 4)->(f, 5)->(g, 6)->(h, 7)->(i, 8)->(j, 9)
4 (a, 0)->(b, 1)->(c, 2)->(d, 3)->(e, 4)->(f, 5)->(g, 6)->(h, 7)->(i, 8)->(j, 9)
```

Time to fulfill our wishes and implement our `map` module. We'll start by defining what it means to be an `empty` map -

```js
// map.js

const empty =
  Symbol("map.empty")

const isEmpty = t =>
  t === empty
```

Next we need a way to insert our entries into the `map`. This calls into existence, `fromEntries`, `set`, `update`, and `node` -

```js
// map.js (continued)

const fromEntries = a =>
  a.reduce((t, [k, v]) => set(t, k, v), empty)

const set = (t, k, v) =>
  update(t, k, _ => v)

const update = (t, k, f) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? node(k, f())
: k < t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, update(t.left, k, f), t.right)
: k > t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, t.left, update(t.right, k, f))
: node(k, f(t.value), t.left, t.right)

const node = (key, value, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ key, value, left, right })
```

Next we'll define a way to `get` a value from our map -

```js
// main.js (continued)

const get = (t, k) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? undefined
: k < t.key
    ? get(t.left, k)
: k > t.key
    ? get(t.right, k)
: t.value
```

And now we'll define a way to `del`ete an entry from our map, which also calls into existence `concat` -

```js
// map.js (continued)

const del = (t, k) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? t
: k < t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, del(t.left, k), t.right)
: k > t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, t.left, del(t.right, k))
: concat(t.left, t.right)

const concat = (l, r) =>
  isEmpty(l)
    ? r
: isEmpty(r)
    ? l
: r.key < l.key
    ? node(l.key, l.value, concat(l.left, r), l.right)
: r.key > l.key
    ? node(l.key, l.value, l.left, concat(l.right, r))
: r
```

Finally we provide a way to visualize the map using `toString`, which calls into existence `inorder`. As a bonus, we'll throw in `toArray` -

```js
const toString = (t) =>
  Array.from(inorder(t), ([ k, v ]) => `(${k}, ${v})`).join("->")

function* inorder(t)
{ if (isEmpty(t)) return
  yield* inorder(t.left)
  yield [ t.key, t.value ]
  yield* inorder(t.right)
}

const toArray = (t) =>
  Array.from(inorder(t))
```

Export the module's features -

```js
// map.js (continued)

export { empty, isEmpty, fromEntries, get, set, update, del, append, inorder, toArray, toString }
```

---

**low hanging fruit**

Your Map module is finished but there are some valuable features we can add without requiring much effort. Below we implement `preorder` and `postorder` map traversals. Additionally we add a second parameter to `toString` and `toArray` that allows you to choose which traversal to use. `inorder` is used by default -

```js
// map.js (continued)

function* preorder(t)
{ if (isEmpty(t)) return
  yield [ t.key, t.value ]
  yield* preorder(t.left)
  yield* preorder(t.right)
}

function* postorder(t)
{ if (isEmpty(t)) return
  yield* postorder(t.left)
  yield* postorder(t.right)
  yield [ t.key, t.value ]
}

const toArray = (t, f = inorder) =>
  Array.from(f(t))

const toString = (t, f = inorder) =>
  Array.from(f(t), ([ k, v ]) => `(${k}, ${v})`).join("->")

export { ..., preorder, postorder }
```

And we can extend `fromEntries` to accept any iterable, not just arrays. This matches the functionality of `Object.fromEntries` and `Array.from` -

```js
// map.js (continued)

function fromEntries(it)
{ let r = empty
  for (const [k, v] of it)
    r = set(r, k, v)
  return r
}
```

Like we did above, we can add a second parameter which allows us to specify how the entries are added into the map. Now it works just like `Array.from`. Why `Object.fromEntries` doesn't have this behaviour is puzzling to me. `Array.from` is smart. Be like `Array.from` -

```js
// map.js (continued)

function fromEntries(it, f = v => v)
{ let r = empty
  let k, v
  for (const e of it)
    ( [k, v] = f(e)
    , r = set(r, k, v)
    )
  return r
}
```

```js
// main.js

import { fromEntries, toString } from "./map.js"

const a =
  [["d",3],["e",4],["g",6],["j",9],["b",1],["a",0],["i",8],["c",2],["h",7],["f",5]]

const z =
  fromEntries(a, ([ k, v ]) => [ k.toUpperCase(), v * v ])

console.log(toString(z))
```

```
(A, 0)->(B, 1)->(C, 4)->(D, 9)->(E, 16)->(F, 25)->(G, 36)->(H, 49)->(I, 64)->(J, 81)
```

---

**demo**

Expand the snippet below to verify the results of our Map module in your own browser -

```js
// map.js
const empty =
  Symbol("map.empty")

const isEmpty = t =>
  t === empty

const node = (key, value, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ key, value, left, right })

const fromEntries = a =>
  a.reduce((t, [k, v]) => set(t, k, v), empty)

const get = (t, k) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? undefined
: k < t.key
    ? get(t.left, k)
: k > t.key
    ? get(t.right, k)
: t.value

const set = (t, k, v) =>
  update(t, k, _ => v)

const update = (t, k, f) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? node(k, f())
: k < t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, update(t.left, k, f), t.right)
: k > t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, t.left, update(t.right, k, f))
: node(k, f(t.value), t.left, t.right)

const del = (t, k) =>
  isEmpty(t)
    ? t
: k < t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, del(t.left, k), t.right)
: k > t.key
    ? node(t.key, t.value, t.left, del(t.right, k))
: concat(t.left, t.right)

const concat = (l, r) =>
  isEmpty(l)
    ? r
: isEmpty(r)
    ? l
: r.key < l.key
    ? node(l.key, l.value, concat(l.left, r), l.right)
: r.key > l.key
    ? node(l.key, l.value, l.left, concat(l.right, r))
: r

function* inorder(t)
{ if (isEmpty(t)) return
  yield* inorder(t.left)
  yield [ t.key, t.value ]
  yield* inorder(t.right)
}

const toArray = (t) =>
  Array.from(inorder(t))

const toString = (t) =>
  Array.from(inorder(t), ([ k, v ]) => `(${k}, ${v})`).join("->")
  
// main.js
const a =
  [["d",3],["e",4],["g",6],["j",9],["b",1],["a",0],["i",8],["c",2],["h",7],["f",5]]

const m =
  fromEntries(a)

console.log(1, toString(m))
console.log(2, toString(del(m, "b")))
console.log(3, toString(set(m, "c", "#")))
console.log(4, toString(m))
console.log(5, get(set(m, "z", "!"), "z"))
```

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15122-f10/lectures/16-randbst.pdf :)

Comment: WillNess, I did want to get into balancing but felt like the topic was maybe too big to breach. I will make the time to read the linked essay. Thanks for sharing :D

Comment: Wonderful answer! One question: does the use of `k < t.key` mean that keys need to be strings or numbers? I.e. is the native `Map` really the only way you can use Objects/Arrays/Functions as keys without having to iterate all elements when doing a lookup? Are there hybrid solutions? (Like using a WeakMap just for storing links between Objects and some generated ID to use as a comparable key in this custom implementation)

Comment: Another interesting inside I've made is regarding the order. If you don't have an order at all or insertion order you can implement a persistent `Map` with a self-balanced and very efficient hashed array mapped Trie. However, if the order is determined by keys/values you need a self-balancing BST, e.g. a finger tree.

Comment: @Thankyou just randomly reshaping it once in a while is good enough, as he describes / hints at / near the end of the lecture (which I found by googling "randomized tree balancing").

Comment: (er, the "randomly" goes with the "once in a while", not "reshaping")

Comment: @user3297291 that's a great question. This answer implements a binary tree using simple `key` and `value` properties, however we often want to store and retrieve more complex values. In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64931549/633183) we examine a more sophisticated btree that allows the user to define precisely how nodes are compared. This tree is flexible enough that you could even supply a hashing function, like in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65100441/633183), such that the tree could handle arbitrarily-shaped nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**functional module**

Here's my little implementation of a persistent `map` module -

```
// map.js

import { effect } from "./func.js"

const empty = _ =>
  new Map

const update = (t, k, f) =>
  fromEntries(t).set(k, f(get(t, k)))

const set = (t, k, v) =>
  update(t, k, _ => v)

const get = (t, k) =>
  t.get(k)

const del = (t, k) =>
  effect(t => t.delete(k))(fromEntries(t))

const fromEntries = a =>
  new Map(a)

export { del, empty, fromEntries, get, set, update }
```

```js
// func.js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f(x), x)

// ...

export { effect, ... }
```

```js
// main.js
import { fromEntries, del, set } from "./map.js"

const q =
  fromEntries([["a",1], ["b",2]])

console.log(1, q)
console.log(2, del(q, "b"))
console.log(3, set(q, "c", 3))
console.log(4, q)
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f(x), x)

const empty = _ =>
  new Map

const update = (t, k, f) =>
  fromEntries(t).set(k, f(get(t, k)))

const set = (t, k, v) =>
  update(t, k, _ => v)

const get = (t, k) =>
  t.get(k)

const del = (t, k) =>
  effect(t => t.delete(k))(fromEntries(t))

const fromEntries = a =>
  new Map(a)

const q =
  fromEntries([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])

console.log(1, q)
console.log(2, del(q, "b"))
console.log(3, set(q, "c", 3))
console.log(4, q)
```

```
1 Map(2) {a => 1, b => 2}
2 Map(1) {a => 1}
3 Map(3) {a => 1, b => 2, c => 3}
4 Map(2) {a => 1, b => 2}
```

---

**object-oriented interface**

If you want to use it in an object-oriented way, you can add a class wrapper around our plain functions. Here we call it `Mapping` because we don't want to clobber the native `Map` -

```js
// map.js (continued)

class Mapping
{ constructor(t) { this.t = t }
  update(k,f) { return new Mapping(update(this.t, k, f)) }
  set(k,v) { return new Mapping(set(this.t, k, v)) }
  get(k) { return get(this.t, k) }
  del(k) { return new Mapping(del(this.t, k)) }
  static empty () { return new Mapping(empty()) }
  static fromEntries(a) { return new Mapping(fromEntries(a))
  }
}

export default Mapping
```

```js
// main.js

import Mapping from "./map"

const q =
  Mapping.fromEntries([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]) // <- OOP class method

console.log(1, q)
console.log(2, q.del("b"))      // <- OOP instance method
console.log(3, q.set("c", 3))   // <- OOP instance method
console.log(4, q)
```

Even though we're calling through OOP interface, our data structure still behaves persistently. No mutable state is used -

```
1 Mapping { t: Map(2) {a => 1, b => 2} }
2 Mapping { t: Map(1) {a => 1} }
3 Mapping { t: Map(3) {a => 1, b => 2, c => 3} }
4 Mapping { t: Map(2) {a => 1, b => 2} }
```